# Saving a matlab figure and keeping all handles

Tags: matlab, save, figure, handles

I am trying to produce a figure in MATLAB with a popupmenu that changes the axes of a subplot. This works so far. But when saving the figure using File > Save, my handles get deleted and it shows me the following error message:

```
Error using struct2handle
Error while evaluating uicontrol CreateFcn

Error using handle.handle/set
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in popup_test/mimi (line 33)
    set(h1,'XData', [0,8],'YData',[0,8])

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

It appeares, that when saving the figure, the handle h1 is deleted. It still is there as a number but `ishandle(h1)` returns 0.

This is the code I have produced my figure with:

```
function popup_test2
figure;
a=magic(4);
h1=imagesc(a);
uicontrol(...
    'Style', 'popup',...
    'String', 'first|second',...
    'Position', [20 340 100 50],...
    'Callback', @popupfcn,...
    'CreateFcn', @popupfcn);

    function popupfcn(hObj,event) %#ok<INUSD>
        % Called when user activates popup menu
        val = get(hObj,'Value');
        if val ==1            
            set(h1,'XData', [0,5],'YData',[0,5])
        elseif val == 2
            set(h1,'XData', [0,8],'YData',[0,8])
        end
    end

end
```

So far I have tried saving using `saveas(gcf,'filename.fig')` (which didn't work) and `hgsave`, which sounded promising, but I didn't know how to use it correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is recreating `h1` after loading the figure. This can be done using the following line of code:

```
h1 = findobj(gcf,'type','image');
```

[`findobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) finds the handle of the plotted image- allowing you to change it as you like.

See final code:

```
function popup_test2
figure;
a=magic(4);
h1=imagesc(a);
uicontrol(...
    'Style', 'popup',...
    'String', 'first|second',...
    'Position', [20 340 100 50],...
    'Callback', @popupfcn,...
    'CreateFcn', @popupfcn);

    function popupfcn(hObj,event) %#ok<INUSD>
        h1=findobj(gcf,'type','image');
        % Called when user activates popup menu
        val = get(hObj,'Value');
        if val ==1            
            set(h1,'XData', [0,5],'YData',[0,5])
        elseif val == 2
            set(h1,'XData', [0,8],'YData',[0,8])
        end
    end

end
```

Please note that saving data/handles along with your figure should generally be done using [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not working for me, because I want to change the properties of the object specified by `imagesc`, rather than the one of the whole subplot. I have edited the example in my question, so that it contains less code and hopefully makes my question clearer.

Comment: See amended answer. The solution is almost identical.