# subplot overwrites content of saved figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have saved a figure, foo.fig, in Matlab, which contains subplots. I later want to open it and change the y-axes on each subplot. For example, say I want to change the axes of subplot 2:

```
hgload('Belle_8_8_14_ch3.fig');
subplot(5,4,2)
set(gca, 'YLim', [0 1])
```

The problem is, when I call `subplot` everything in panel 2 is overwritten. How do I stop this?

I have lots of these plots, so I cannot do it simply by clicking and changing them manually with the GUI.

Note this is only a problem with a figure I have saved and reopened, but unfortunately I need to do this for this application.

**Related content**

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/85219-subplot-of-already-saved-figures

Comment: This is answered [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/236202).

Comment: So there is no way to do it cleanly, without creating a new figure and copying its contents over? Maybe there is a better way to do it since that 2008 post came out :)

Comment: You didn't read the post. It tells you to use `findobj` to get the handle and then set the current axes to it.

Comment: @NKN that doesn't help. The second you do subplot(x,y,z), panel z is overwritten completely.

Comment: Anon how to find handle corresponding to particular subplot?

Comment: Something like `get( gca(), 'children' )`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61448/discussion-between-neuronet-and-anonsubmitter85).

Comment: [This post is also somewhat related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378680/saving-a-matlab-figure-and-keeping-all-handles/25380289#25380289)